# How to start a background process via command line on IOS?

Tags: python, ios, process, background, cydia

I'm trying to launch a background process (a `Python` daemon to be exact) on my `iPod`  (`ios 6.1.6` *jailbroken*), but the `Python` process gets suspended eventually by the os.

Here are the things I tried to make it run in background:

- Launch the process via `MobileTerminal`. It gets suspended when I hit the home button, same when installing `MobileTerminal` `Backgrounder` or configuring the `MobileTerminal` app to run in background mode with `Background Manager`.
- `SSH` connect and launch the process with `nohup`, it also gets suspended. Setting the highest priority with nice also does not work.

Does anyone have some ideas how to achieve this? This must be possible, because processes like the openssh server seem to have permanent background.

I looked on the internet for quite a while, and the only helpful thing I found that might work is to set up a launch daemon, but this makes it not easy to stop / restart the process if I have to restart the device, and I do not know if it works for sure.

Thanks.